# Expanding a relative path to a full path when running a C program in shell

Tags: c, bash, argv, shebang

I have a problem when my script needs to communicate with a C executable. I cannot get the script's full path, which I need to load and send to another process.

The script's name is `myScript`

```
#!/home/user/git/proyect/test

hello this

is a
script
```

and this is the source code of the C executable

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    int count;

    printf ("Este programa fue llamado con: \"%s\".\n",argv[0]);
    if (argc > 1){
        for (count=1; count<argc; count++){
            printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", count, argv[count]);
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("The command had no other arguments.\n");
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

If I run `myScript` from terminal,

- `argv[0]` shows the executable's path (I guess that's because it's the info at `#!`).
- `argv[1]` shows the first argument passed to the executable, i.e.

  - if I use `./myScript` as the argument, that is what I see (the relative path)
  - if I use `/home/user/git/proyect/test/scriptFolder/myScript` as the argument, it shows the absolute path (which is what I need, but I don't want to write the full path in terminal every time)

So my question is, how do I get the full path of `myScript` without passing its full path when calling the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not very well worded so I am not sure I am answering the same question that you are asking, but you can convert "./myScript" to its full path using the [realpath()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realpath.html) function.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was looking for. realpath()
Should I edit my question with full working code?

Comment: But I want, so the answer stays as example for future. I mean, if I want to do it, editing question is OK or should add it as comment or something?

Comment: Oh, sure, editing question is ok.  Just append at the end, start with "UPDATE:"

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you are implementing a script parser/interpreter.

The `main` function you present here is compiled and linked to the `/home/user/git/proyect/test` executable. Am i right?

That means that when you execute `./myScript` on the terminal what is actually executed is `/home/user/git/proyect/test ./myScript`.

If this is the case @MK's answer is right. And with `realpath()` you can get the absolute path of "./myScript"

I would suggest editing your question to be more readable.